# Video element displays only controls

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a problem in regards to the `video` element inside HTML5 when using Google Chrome version 54.0.2840.99. 
The relevant HTML looks like this.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Something</legend>

    <div class="well">
        <video style="width:200px; height:200px" controls>
            <source src="Myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8/VP9 or MP4 with H.264.
        </video>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

The result that I get is this:

[image]

I mention that there are no problems when opening the web page from Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer. Also, I do not get any error messages inside the console.

Any help in solving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The problem is that the video that I want to see its not loaded by the `video` element inside Chrome. I have also checked the MIME types supported by the IIS Server and there everything it is fine.

Comment: Please describe the problem.

Comment: @GibboK, I have updated my question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: your markup works well for what I see, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/yjxnqcan/

Comment: did you check your video encoding? Could you provide url to your video?

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is running on localhost, therefore I cannot do that. May I ask what do you mean by the encoding of the video?

Comment: you can post your video online and provide an url here. We can double check it for you :)

Comment: Here it goes... http://www.filedropper.com/nightcore-doitlikeadude .